# Impulse response with initial conditions on python using filter/filtic

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I am trying to get impulse response using filter/filtic at rest and initial conditions.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal

n = np.arange(0,8,1)

h = np.array([1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]) #unit impulse signal

a = np.array([1,1/2,1/4])
b = np.array([1,2,1/4])   #a & b are filter coeficients

plt.figure(1)

y1 = signal.lfilter(b,a,h) 
plt.stem(n,y1)
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel("n")
plt.ylabel("Impulse response")
plt.title("Impulse response with initial rest")

## With initial condition

x1 = np.array([-1,0])
x2 = np.array([-1/2,1])

z1 = signal.lfiltic(b,a,x1,x2)
y11 = signal.lfiltic(b,a,h,z1)

plt.figure(2)
plt.stem(n,y11)
```

While I got impulse response at rest, but i am getting an error while using initial conditions.
This is the error I am getting

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\Hp.spyder-py3\untitled1.py", line 32, in 
> plt.stem(n,y11)
>
> File "C:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py",
> line 3134, in stem
> return gca().stem(
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib_*init*_.py", line
> 1361, in inner
> return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_axes.py",
> line 2873, in stem
> stemlines = xlines(
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib_*init*_.py", line
> 1361, in inner
> return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_axes.py",
> line 1115, in vlines
> masked_verts[:, 1, 1] = ymax
>
> File "C:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\ma\core.py",
> line 3375, in **setitem**
> _data[indx] = dval
>
> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,) into shape
> (8,)

Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to obtain the filter response with initial condition you're using `lfiltic` two times in a row. You need to use the response from the first `lfiltic` (`z1`) in the `lfilter` command, similarly with what you've done in the first block, but now passing `z1` to the `zi` function parameter.

```py
...
z1 = signal.lfiltic(b,a,x1,x2)
y11 = signal.lfilter(b,a,h,zi=z1)

plt.figure(2)
plt.title("Impulse response with initial condition")
plt.stem(n,y11[0])
```

[image: filter_with_initial_conditions]